# change the text for meridiem (am pm) in bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to change the language in the boostrap datetime picker and I used the below code

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({'format':'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A','locale':'fr'});
```

I also added required js file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
```

This changes the language of the calendar, but the time picker still show AM/PM 
[image]

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HH` or `H` for 24 hour format and remove `A` for the AM/PM:

`$('.date').datetimepicker({'format':'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm','locale':'fr'});`

You can find more about Moment.js formats [here](https://momentjs.com/)

**Edit**: To change the AM/PM you can overwrite the locale meridiem:

```
moment.locale('fr', {
meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
        return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
    }
});
```

More info about it you can find [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)

Comment: thank you
I am looking to change the text in the AM/PM buttons, any way to change that?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstand you can change the locale meridiem. I'll edit the answer

Comment: yeah this is what I was looking for !
Appreciate your help :) Accepted the answer